# ¿Xampp o Apache tienen una caché que puede interferir con la actualización correcta de los scripts (js)?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, xampp, cache

Tengo mis paginas locales alojadas en XAMPP.

Cuando construyo una web con mucho codigo, html, css, scripts, y la dejo mucho tiempo sin modificar, y de pronto le hago un cambio radical a la estructura (html/css) y a los scripts (animaciones js), digamos renuevo el codigo en un 70%, los nuevos calculos de los scripts fallan...reviso mi codigo y la consola y no tengo errores...vaceo la cache de mi navegador por completo (desde el inicio de los tiempos), y lo unico que soluciona es el html y css, es decir me muestra los cambios realizados en esas hojas pero no los cambios de los scripts.... cuando vuelvo a poner las animaciones como estaban originalmente en el script, en la misma posicion, con la misma sintaxis, etc, se arregla la pagina (es como si los calculos estuvieran ya asentados, y cualquier nuevo cambio los desconfigura)....esto siempre pasa con los metodos de java script y jquery: POSITION, OFFSET, OFFSETHEIGHT, HEIGHT, etc, cualquiera que tenga que ver con calculos en una estructura que acabo de modificar (los scripts que fallan estan en un documento aparte .js)...Por esta razon estoy pensando que, aparte de la memoria cache del navegador, debe haber otra memoria, quiza del xampp o apache, que no me esta actualizando los scripts...otro dato importante es que, si dejo pasar el tiempo, digamos una semana o mas, los cambios se hacen correctamente de manera automatica como por arte de magia, se arreglan las posiciones, los tamaños, etc...esto es una señal mas de que un cache esta funcionando cuando le da la gana. Y me retrasa, porque ahora no se si mi codigo esta bien (y en una semana se va a arreglar solo) o si hay algo mal en el codigo que debo solucionar.

Comment: En la mayoria de navegadores puedes forzar el refresco de cache con "ctrl + f5", aun asi, la propia dev console de ellos, suele tener una opcion para evitar la cache. Ten en cuenta que los navegadores para ganar velocidad, almacenan los archivos en cache, si haces cambios, el navegador seguira cargando la versión cacheada. Aunque si por ejemplo, esa pagina local es un prestashop, tendras que borrar la cache de prestashop

Comment: no funciona con control f5.........y no, no uso ningun cms....estoy trabajando en local con xampp, haciendo una pagina a medida desde cero

Answer (score 0):

Sí, el servidor hace cacheo para minimizar lecturas a disco y así mejorar su desempeño.
Para fines de desarrollo puedes simplemente agregar un *query string* falso/aleatorio al incluir el archivo js, de tal manera que el servidor proveerá una versión actualizada. Algo como `archivo.js?ver=123`.